# In an angular CLI app is there a way to not load the centralized CSS/SCSS for a particular component

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli

In an angular CLI app is there a way to not load the centralized CSS/SCSS for a particular component.
The `.angular-cli.json` looks like this:

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      ....
      ....
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css"
      ],
   ]
```

However, for one component I don't want to load styles.scss as its ruining all my styles by overriding them. It there a workaround/hack to fix this.

Comment: By default, your component's styles are not the part of global style scope and shouldn't be affected by global CSS styles as described in [this docs section](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope). Have you tried debugging with generated CSS? Perhaps, actual component code sample and place where exactly problem occurs would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can include in component `selector`-

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

Reference Link:- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

The components styles are loaded in last after all centralized styles are loaded, so, component.css can override parent.css but parent.css can't override component.css . However, centralized(parent) css will be applied throughout the app, if not overrided in component itself.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to make that component to use `ViewEncapsulation.Native`.

With `Native` Angular will use the true shadow DOM which is meant to truly encapsulate your component, so no styles will bleed out and no style from ancestors will be injected in.

However, make sure you understand the limitation.